# Join / Sort Domain Name Column to Company Name Column (Fuzzy) Sheets

Tags: database, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pattern-matching

I have a list of columns in a Google Sheet.

(ID, name, title, company name) and then I have a domain column though the data in that column doesn't line up with the other respective columns. For example for the first row the domain should be pgconsulting.net not nixon.com as shown below. And so forth.

```
ID, Name, title, company, domain

02, Eric Mensin, CEO, PG Consulting,  
Nixon.com
03, Nick Doe, Director, Nixon, 
pgconsulting.net
04, Erin Mathews, Manager, Streetz, 
poolcues.io
```

Is there anyway to ensure that the correct domain appears next to it's respective Company name (and the thereby correctly match the rest of the columns).

Thanks and your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You mean the 5th column is actually on its own row? If that's the case can you not just move them all to be in the proper place? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Why don't the rows line up with the domains in the domain column?

Comment: I meant the data in the domains column doesn't correspond with the respective company name data etc. It's not in the right order.  The reason for this is because the first four columns were collected at the same time, but data for the domain column was collected separately. So although the domain name column contains the correct data it's not aligned with corresponding values on other column rows. Does that make sense?  I'll post a screenshot in a minute.

Comment: How do you know that it's the correct data?

Comment: Because I reversed the process harvesting results using company names from search engines (i.e. intitle:company name or "company name") etc from a search engine.

So I have the right data it just isn't sorted accordingly to link up with the rest of data in other columns, As per above ^ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I discovered to make it work.

IF value exists in one cell match value based on another cell next to it.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(G2,J:J, 0)), "No Match", VLOOKUP(G2,J:K,2,FALSE))
```

In the above example, the G column contains the correctly ordered company names and the function is taking the value in G2 (in this case a company name) and trying to find it in the J column.

If not found the cell will display the "No Match". However, if found it will take the value located next to the J column (in this case domains are located in column K).

---

If you have two columns of domains and you want to choose the best one based on filters (in this case if the column contains facebook, or linkedin)

```
=SWITCH(L2,"linkedin.com",H2,"",L2,"facebook.com",H2,"")
```

And then if you want to combine best domain chosen, you can use the following code:

```
=IF(LEN(M2),M2,L2)
```